# Android developer Google map api v2

Tags: android, eclipse, dictionary

I'm building my first app which uses Google Map, in Eclipse + SDK.
I use some SHA1 code for encryption.

I tried to test it on the Genymotion emulator and debug it on my real device by using the usb cable.

The application runs.
The problem is that when I export the apk file and install it on my device, the application doesn't run.

Please, help me !

Comment: when you connect the device with computer is it working nicely??

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting. Now the question is more readable.

Comment: Sorry guys for bad grammar.
When i connect the device with computer, the application work fine
but when i export apk file and install on device, the application dont run as i desired

Answer (score 0):

If the application works fine when the device is connected with the computer and apk crashes when run it in device.Then may be you have problem with generated apk file.As you are using `eclipse` take the `apk` file from your project `bin folder` after building it.When you will build the project it will create a `apk` file at the bin folder of your project.Just take it and install it.

Comment: i dont take apk from bin folder, but i use Eclipse to Export Signed Application Package and install that apk.
The application after that doesnt CRASH, but it can't load the map, and i think i miss something, but i dont know exactly what it is

Comment: can emulator load map??

Comment: yes. emulator can load map, and real device with debug can do it too